# How to make a user in 'users' owner of a note in 'notes'? PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How do I make a person in 'users'-table an owner of a note in 'notes'-table?
 e.g.:

I want id "1" from table 'users' to be owner of id "2" from table 'notes'.

EDIT: I'm using a logged in session for 'users'

'users' is:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(70) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and 'notes' is:

```
CREATE TABLE `notes` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `created` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now(),
  `edited` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now() ON UPDATE now(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is my 'notes' code(how do I include 'users' as explained on top):

```
public function fetchNotes($id = null) {
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT title, content FROM notes WHERE id = :id');
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
}

public function create($title, $content) {
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO notes (title, content, created) VALUES (:title, :content, null)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $stmt->bindParam(':content', $content);
    $stmt->execute();
}

public function delete($id) {
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM notes WHERE id = :id');
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
}

public function edit($id, $title, $content) {
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('UPDATE notes SET title = :title, content = :content WHERE id = :id');
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $stmt->bindParam(':content', $content);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: you need to pass the `userid` value to `public function create($title, $content){...}`. Do you store the logged in `\`users\`.\`id\`` in a session, or other method?

Comment: why don't you just pass the user_id as param to create() function and then fetch it in fetchNotes() in such way: "SELECT title, content, user_id, ...." ?

Comment: I did what you said, but now how do I exactly make user_id(id of users) owner of a note under create(INSERT...)?

Comment: @Sean yes, its in a logged in session

Comment: @Sean so it's like this?: `$user_id = $_SESSION['id'];` and then `INSERT INTO notes (..., user_id=:user_id, ...)` and bindParam it?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Make a column named "user_id" and make it equal to "id" of 'users'-table. Then you check with an if-command if SESSION['id'] == row['user_id'] anywhere you want it to check...